# Op type not registered 'MaxBytesInUse' in binary running on DESKTOP

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use custom dateset while using code of stylegan. 
when it building tensorflow graph the following error will come:
ValueError: Op type not registered 'MaxBytesInUse' in binary running on DESKTOP. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed. while building NodeDef 'MaxBytesInUse'

I am new to deep learning 
your help will be great favour for me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: i also use different versions of tensorflow but same result

Answer (score 0):

in stylgan repo, itst recommended to use TensorFlow 1.10.0 which led to the "MaxByteinUse" error,
changing to'tensorflow-gpu==1.11.0' worked for me